# Aggregation: transforming JSON structure in mongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a json

```
{
    "_id": "560253036e1316b021b90a55",
    "mood": "meh",
    "timestamp": "092315"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5602564b6e1316b021b90a56",
    "mood": "happy",
    "timestamp": "092315"
  }
```

that will be transformed by using aggreagte in mongodb, my working code is

```
`db.mood.aggregate(
        [{
            $match : {
                timestamp : sixDigitDate //its a simple function that returns 6 days
            }
        },
            {
                $group : {
                    _id : "$mood",
                    total : {
                        $sum : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
        )
`
```

which outputs the json in a format like this

```
[
      {
        "_id": "meh",
        "total": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": "happy",
        "total": 1
      }
]
```

what I want to accomplish is to have a json to output like this format:

```
{    //the ID will be the date.
     date : 092315,
     "meh" : 1,
     "happy" : 1
 } 
{
     date : 092317,
     "meh" : 2,
     "happy" : 3
}
```

any hints on where to start?

Comment: so you also want to convert timestamp to float. right?

Comment: the time-stamp is not that important (i can play around it if i have time), i just want to aggregate the data that ti will be displayed on that way. I'm a newbie in aggregation

Comment: @user3100115 I think the point is to group a document with a list of "moods" by date. Which of course cannot be done unless you accept an array of moods for output or at least have a ":defined list" of moods since the aggregation framework cannot create arbitrary keys.